# R-markdown figures captions in greek text

Tags: r, r-markdown, xelatex

I am trying to write a report in R markdown and use the Greek language instead of English although in most parts of the report (plain text, figure text etc.) the language is implemented correctly in the figure captions the text returns the format: <U+0391><U+03BD>a<U+03BB><U+03BF><U+03B3><U+03AF>a...... instead of actual greek text.

````
```{r, echo= FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.cap="Αναλογία φύλων του \\textit{Juniperus drupacea} στο όρος Πάρνωνας, αριθμός ατόμων που ελέγχθηκαν: 488, αριθμός περιοχών δειγματοληψίας: 11, Θ: Θυληκά, Ν: νεαρά, Α: αρσενικά."}
````

i have set my local system into Greek, using Xelatex as an Enginge, PDF-Cairo but the problem keeps coming up.
Any ideas??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please add the results from `sessionInfo()` to your question? By the way, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

There is a related question [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/greek-unicode-in-r-markdown/20870/4). Using this approach, this worked for me, although I am not sure if this is what you're looking for:

````
---
title: "Greek"
author: "bttomio"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Arial
monofont: "Courier New"
monofontoptions: "Scale=0.7"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r pressure, fig.cap="Αναλογία φύλων του \\textit{Juniperus drupacea} στο όρος Πάρνωνας, αριθμός ατόμων που ελέγχθηκαν: 488, αριθμός περιοχών δειγματοληψίας: 11, Θ: Θυληκά, Ν: νεαρά, Α: αρσενικά."}
plot(pressure)
```
````

-output

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. But still i get the same problem, maybe i am missing something? trying to replicate your example with the exact same code as posted above: the figure captions goes like this:      Figure 1: <U+0391><U+03BD>a<U+03BB><U+03BF><U+03B3><U+03AF>a
f<U+03CD><U+03BB><U+03C9><U+03BD> t<U+03BF><U+03C5> Juniperus drupacea st<U+03BF>.....

Comment: Try reinstalling `xelatex`

Comment: I have the same problem but i use pdflatex engine.